# Modify a sub-part of a sub-list only

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have this list:

```
a = {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}
```

and I'd like to transform it to this:

```
a = {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{0, 0}, {1, Na}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}
```

ie I'd like to replace every 0 by Na except in the first sub-sub-list of each sub-list.

All I can come up with is:

```
Part[#, 2 ;; All, All] & /@ a  /. 0 -> Na
```

and it works I get

```
{{{1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{1, Na}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}
```

but the modification is not attributed to `a`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `a = Part[#, 2 ;; All, All] & /@ a  /. 0 -> Na` or perhaps you intended to modify the original copy of `a` ?

Comment: yes I need to modify the original copy of a your solution below works thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This will work if all your first elements of the sub-lists are of the form {0,0}

```
a = a /. {{x_?Positive, 0} :> {x, Na}};
a
```

> {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{0, 0}, {1, Na}, {2, 
>      1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}

Answer (score 4):

This is a good case for `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) and `ApplyTo` (new
in 12.2)

```
list =
  {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}},
   {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}};

list //= ReplaceAt[{x_, 0} :> {x, Na}, {All, 2 ;;}];

list
```

{{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}},
{{0, 0}, {1, Na}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}

Answer (score 3):

Another quick possibility

```
a=a/. {n_, r:{_Integer,_Integer}...} :> Join[{n},{ r} /. 0->Na]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
a = {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 
    1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}

SubsetMap[ReplaceAll[0 -> Na], #, 2 ;;] & /@ a
```

---

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
MapIndexed[If[Last@#2 > 1, ReplaceAll[#1, 0 -> Na], #1] &, a, {2}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}, {{0, 0}, {1, Na}, {2,
> 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 7}}}

---

```
WolframLanguageData["SubsetMap", {"VersionIntroduced", 
  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplacePart` and `Cases` as follows:

```
a = {{{1, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 0}}, 
     {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 7}}, 
     {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}};

patt1 = {x1_, x2_} /; x1 != 0 && x2 == 0;

pos[l_List] := Position[l, patt1]

parts[l_List] := Cases[l, patt1 -> {x1, Na}, 2]

patt2 = Rule[lhs_, rhs_] /; lhs[[2]] != 1;

rep[l_List] := Cases[Thread[pos[#] -> parts[#]] &@l, patt2]

ReplacePart[#, rep[#]] &@a

(*{{{1, 0}, {1, 7}, {2, Na}, {3, 2}, {4, Na}},
   {{1, 0}, {1, Na}, {2, 1}, {3, Na}, {4, 7}},
   {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, Na}, {3, 1}, {4, Na}}}*)
```

Comment: The requirement is to change 0's except in the first element of each sublist. Your solution works if such entries are `{0,0}`. Can you improve it perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the limitation of the first code, @Syed :-)